# find a function continuous at 1

Tags: limits, functions

Find all the functions $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ continuous in the point $x_0=1$ for which $f(9x−8)−2f(3x−2)+f(x)=4x−4$, $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Let $g:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $g(x)=f(x)-x$, then the initial condition is rewritten as $g(9x-8)-2g(3x-2)+g(x)=0$. Now define again $h:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $h(x)=g(x)-g(3x-2)$ and the previous relation rewrites as $h(x)=h(3x-2)$.

Comment: can you find one such $f$?

Comment: The function $f(x)=x$ seems fine to me

Comment: Well, $h$ is not really periodic. But from $h(x+1)=h(3x+1)$ we see that $x\mapsto h(e^x+1)$ is periodic with period $\ln 3$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are given that $f$ is continuous at $x_0=1$. Then $g$ and $h$ are also continuous at $x_0=1$.  Let $k(x)=h(e^x+1)$. In fact it is *this* function, not $h$ that is periodic: $$k(x+\ln 3)=h(3e^x+1)=h(3(e^x+1)-2)=h(e^x+1)=k(x). $$
Continuity of $h$ at $x_0=1$ means that $\lim_{x\to-\infty} k(x)$ exists. Since $k$ is periodic, $k$ must be constant. So $h$ is constant on $(1,\infty)$, by continuity also in $[1,\infty)$. We conclude $h(x)=h(1)=g(1)-g(1)=0$ for $x\ge 1$. The same argument works with $k(x)=h(1-e^x)$, showing that $h$ is also constant on $(-\infty,1]$, so $h(x)=0$ for all $x$.

Now we have $g(x)=g(3x-2)$ and $g$ is continuous at $x_0=1$. The same reasoning as for $h$ applies, i.e., $g$ is constant.
We conclude that $$f(x)=x+c.$$
On the other hand, we immediately verify that these functions are indeed solutions to the given functional equation.